# Healthy Resting Heart Rate

Tags: health, heart-rate, health-risk

I've read that a normal resting heart rate is anywhere from 60-100 BPM, which is  a huge, unhelpful range. The charts I've seen seem to contradict this normal range, where they say that a RHR in the 80s is on the unhealthy side. So, which is it?

I'm a 30 year old male, 5'2", 130lbs and I live a pretty sedentary life style. So, should I be worried that my RHR is around 85-88?

Answer (score 4):

Heart Rate is an individual measure.
I have 60. My colleague, who is much fitter than me has 80.
Some ultra marathon runner I know has 30.

The range is unhelpful huge because RHR is an unhelpful measure.
What you can watch out for is changes. You have 80 now, if it changes to 60 without you training much? it's time to see a doctor. It changes to 120? Time to see a doctor faster.

Answer (score 0):

I have heart problem where my heart would sometimes skip a beat. With that being said I also asked my doctor about something similar to your question once and he said if you're in normal condition (without doing exercise or anything) it's should usually be around 70-80 BPM. 
I'm not sure if everyone is different but mine's like that. So hope that helps :D

Answer (score 0):

**Short answer:**

If you care about your health, you should be worried.

**Long answer:**

Based on:

*Maffetone P. The big book of endurance training and racing. Skyhorse Publishing, Inc.; 2010 Sep 22.*

RHR is an important measure of overall health. It is a indicator of your aerobic function level.

In general, the lower RHR the better. As a healthy RHR could be considered lower than 60. The world standards are higher, because it is based on sample of people where are a lot of unhealthy people (Note the difference between "healthy" and "able to work").

A lot of people are fit (can finish marathon or deadlift 3xBW), but they are not healthy. Some people are also exceptions. If you care about health, do not listen exceptions or unhealthy but fit people.

**Note:** Make sure you measure your RHR correctly. Best is at the morning, directly in the bed before you get up. Repeat at least 10 days and make an average. Also It is negatively influenced by any stress in previous days (training, work stress, junk food...). It could be also influenced (in any direction) by some serious health issue.